# What is the need to introduce interfaces, when we already have its super-set abstract classes?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract

Abstract classes contains both types of methods - abstract (non-implemented) as well as concrete (implemented) methods. While interfaces contain only non-implemented methods. It means interfaces are subset of abstract classes. Then why the interfaces was introduced in C# (.Net)? According to me, there are two reasons for it:

1. To support multiple inheritance
2. To support inheritance for value types (structs) in C#.

Is there any other reason or some hidden concept which I am missing?

Comment: `C#` doesn't support multiple inheritance. A class can implement multiple interfaces and subclass a single class. And that's a sufficient reason for including interfaces in the language.

Comment: I have already mentioned this point in my question using 'multiple inheritance'. Please suggest some point other than two points which I have mentioned.

Comment: I'll repeat: `C#` **doesn't** support multiple inheritance. and please try to have some more respect to the users here. We are trying to help you after all.

Comment: To be fair, "inherit" and "implement", while I understand are separate concepts, are pretty subtle distinctions that not everyone gets. Given that the syntax is the same in C# (unlike Java where you have two separate keywords) I can see why someone might think in terms of "inheriting" from an interface. Given that, the OP did at least imply in his original post that C# doesn't support multiple inheritance _other than through_ interfaces.

Comment: A variation on your argument, @ManishDubey: Since you can inherit from multiple interfaces but you can only inherit from a single class, classes must be a subset of interfaces. I also wish people would stop complaining about that implementation/inheritance deal. It's a bit like Stallman saying you shouldn't say `Linux`, you should say `GNU slash Linux`.

Answer (score 8):

What you're missing is considering the relationship between the two classes.

Inheritance (which you use with abstract classes) is an `is-a` relationship. So if you were developing an application for a vet clinic you might create an Animal abstract class and then create Cat, Dog, Bird, and Fish from that, because Cat `is-a` Animal, Dog `is-a` Animal, etc.

Interface implementation defines a `can-do` relationship. Perhaps you want to be able to Print several things in your application (Invoice, Animal, CustomerProfile). You shouldn't use inheritance (i.e. abstract class) for that because Invoice `is-a` Print doesn't make any sense, however Invoice `can-do` Print, CustomerProfile `can-do` Print does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are used to decouple components in an application; in order to avoid relationships that might impact a whole system, there must exist a partitioning in your application that separates it into abstract and concrete components.

Concrete components must point towards the abstract components, else changes in implementation may impact the whole architecture. The partitions may exist on different facets of the application but they must always respect this principle to ensure that the application doesn't become fragile.

**Interface is a way to promise that no implementation exists in a contract**, and that components referencing this contract won't be subject to a change in the implementation of this contract down the line. Abstract classes cannot make this guarantee because they allow implementation. Even if you decide to use pure abstract classes, some other developer may add some tiny implementation as a shortcut because it helps down the line. How could you tell?

Of course it would be possible to decide that a new keyword needs to be applied to the pure abstract class to let the compiler check that it is indeed a pure abstraction... and the interface concept is back!

That is the reason why the interface concept needs to exist in .Net and why abstract classes aren't enough by themselves

---

Edit to add: funnily enough i was watching [the Interface Segregation Principle episode of the "Clean Code" series by Robert Martin](http://cleancoders.com/episode/clean-code-episode-12/show), and he states in this episode that interfaces in languages such as java or C# are the result of unwillingness/laziness from the part of the designers to tackle the problem of [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) (and he illustrates with the Deadly Triangle of Death). I may have been trying to justify the interface because it exists rather than thinking about the reason for its existence, but I still think that the interface is a useful construct that guarantees the absence of code in behavioral definition.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons you list are both valid (interfaces aren't truly multiple inheritance, but it's true that classes can implement multiple interfaces). These are the primary advantages from a pure functionality perspective, and they are very important ones.

Additionally, though, interfaces are often seen as "cleaner" than abstract classes and thus have several design advantages. With an interface, all members can be overridden, guaranteeing ultimate flexibility to a consumer who wants to provide their own implementation. With abstract classes, the mix of sealed, abstract, and virtual methods can make it difficult to grok as a consumer. Not only do you have to understand the API of each method, but also you need to understand how the default implementations interact. For example, let's say you wanted to implement a custom collection class which prints each element as it is added. Imagine there's a base class with 2 methods:

```
virtual void Add(T item);
virtual void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items);
```

We start by overriding Add() to be:

```
override void Add(T item) { Console.WriteLine(item); base.Add(item); }
```

However, what do we do about AddRange()? If we know that the default implementation of AddRange() calls Add() under the hood, then we don't have to override it at all. On the other hand, if the default implementation does something different (maybe calls some method AddInternal() which is also called by Add()), then we have to override AddRange() to explicitly call Add().

Forcing yourself to use interfaces instead of abstract classes can thus make for cleaner, more flexible APIs. With abstract classes, each sealed method is a potential loss of flexibility (and could often be replaced by an extension method on an interface), and each virtual method can make things more complex for consumers.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is semantic: an interface declares contract of behavior ("what it can do?"), while a class (including abstract one) declares particular implementation ("how it is done?").

Having this, "pure abstract class", as class without implementation, indeed can act as interface (if we imagine that CLR supports multiple inheritance).

But "can act" doesn't mean "supposed to". `object[]` can act as `List<int>`, or we can use `delegate` instead `event`, or we can use switch by type instead generics etc - but in C#, in CLR it will be just wrong. But still possible.

So answering your question - you shouldn't think about formal differences, you should think about semantic. And in C# interfaces are used to declare "what it can do".

You even might see completely empty interfaces - just because someone wanted to "mark" anything which implements such empty interface as satisfying someone needs - and that's purely semantic and fully "legal" usage of interface.